# What does the "@" do in SQL*Plus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I found this line in a sql code:

```
@../../sql_scripts/create_tables.sql
```

What does it do? I know that `@@file.sql` means that file.sql is run and `@` could be used when we want to supply parameter values later, but here I have `@` followed by a filename. I know that there is a similar question but it covers only `@` in queries.

Comment: @DarkCthulhu - Not a duplicate of that question. This is not a parameter here. Sorin what tool processes this SQL?

Comment: My mistake. Not the same question.

Comment: What do you mean by SQL, TSQL, PSQL or something else with SQL style syntax? The code in your question is not valid as standard SQL. You are probably using some preprocessor that treats that line as an include or execute.

Comment: This question should be reopened as it is not a duplicate. The `@` here does not have the same meaning as in the other question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here the `@` is not part of the SQL language. It is likely a command for the SQL interpreter which is probably Oracle SQL*Plus.

SQL*Plus has many single-character commands like `@` or `/` (which executes buffered SQL), `;` which can be puzzling when you encounter them in an `.sql` file.

`@` is documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1006685) in Oracle 9i documentation. There you will see the differences with `@@`.

[documentation for Oracle 11g Release 2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve002.htm#i2696724), click Next section for @@ reference.

Comment: looks a likely candidate.

Answer (score 1):

The `@` allows you to import another script into the sql script you're running in SQL*Plus.

For example, this executes the contents of `otherscript.sql` at the specified point:

```
PROMPT about to run other script

@otherscript.sql

PROMPT finished running other script
```

Another example, this inserts the contents of another file into the middle of a statement to be executed in SQL*Plus:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE
@predicates_for_mytable.sql
AND bla = 1;
```

The only condition is that `@` must appear at the 1st character on the line.